# Unable to create 12.04 boot CD or DVD

Tags: live-usb, cd-image, livedvd

I am trying to upgrade my PC to 12.04, so I downloaded the .iso desktop file to burn onto a CD or DVD.

Before creating the disk I first made a bootable USB stick (using pendrive), this worked fine in one PC but not in the one I need to upgrade, I suspect due to BIOS not supporting this feature.

So I have tried to create both a boot CD and DVD, using various burning programs:

1. Using Windows 7, right click on the .iso file
2. CDBurnerXP
3. ImgBurn, selecting the write image file to disk option.

In every case the CD or DVD just has the one .iso file written to it, there is no file structure.

However, if I look at the USB stick I created from the same .iso file it has the files I expect to see, and it works. So what is going wrong here, I've never had this issue in the past, and am totally out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried changing your boot order?

Comment: He did not manage to burn the iso image -- instead of burning the image, he just created a cd containing a single file -- the image.

Comment: sorry suffering from headaches here :( try http://infrarecorder.org/ and make sure you choose the burn image option.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried several burners now, on all I specified burn image, no joy, very frustrating. Am going to try the network upgrade approach. Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Free ISO Burner](http://www.freeisoburner.com/).  It is completely free for personal and non-commercial use, no adware and no spyware, you can use, copy, email, install and uninstall as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think I may have already tried that one, will take another look.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea -- this is really a Windows question. The ISO files are OK, as thousands of users who successfully used them to install Ubuntu can testify.

However, if you have a Ubuntu with a CD writer somewhere, then burning the CD is as easy as writing

```
wodim filename.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer already has a version of Ubuntu on it you might want to consider upgrading via terminal. with these command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Yesm this sounds like a plan, will give it a go.