# Problems burning Ubuntu onto a CD - too big

Tags: installation, windows, cd, windows-vista

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto a CD, but I'm running into a problem; namely that my CD can only hold 702MB of data, yet the iso itself when I try to burn it becomes 736MB.

What am I doing wrong in burning? Thank you in advance. Or what should I do?

On another note, a DVD is not an option, since I have an old laptop...and I'm not sure if my USB stick which is also pretty old can be booted from. So any and all advice regarding either how to burn to a CD, checking if my USB can be booted from, or alternatives to Ubuntu I can use would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you burning the ISO? What software are you using?

Comment: Through drag and drop + burn, InfraRecorder (no success even in pretending it'll burn) and CDBurnerXP which goes through the motions of burning, doesn't succeed at the end.

Comment: Check out my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178951/unable-to-create-12-04-boot-cd-or-dvd)

Comment: Tried USB, no luck, my USB stick can't boot...and I don't understand why it's not burning onto the CD...I'm at a loss. :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all please ensure that you are downloading Ubuntu from an [official mirror](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
Also [read](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) the instructions for burning a CD on Windows.

Comment: I have downloaded from the official mirror, and my computer does not burn like that, rather I dragged the iso onto the CD and hit burn from there, using its native one. I also used CDBurnerXP.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows Vista Home Premium 32bit

Comment: I have modified the read link in my answer.Please go through the entire page once.Also try decreasing the write speed.

Comment: Alright, just to confirm a few things.
1. My disc is 80minutes.
2. I downloaded InfraRecorder, but despite this when I load the iso file, it won't let me hit the 'ok' option to burn. Not sure what that implies other than maybe it can't. I know my laptop can read and write CDs, so I'm at a bit of a loss...also, despite being 99% sure it can't, I will try with my USB stick and hope for the best.

Comment: Are you sure that the CD you were using was empty and not corrupted?I would suggest that buy a new CD instead or try the USB option!

Comment: I've tried it with quite a few discs (Silverline), they can't all be corrupted.

Comment: Tried USB, no luck, my USB stick can't boot...and I don't understand why it's not burning onto the CD...I'm at a loss. :/

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Create a bootable USB stick, they are cheap these days and you can easily port it around. During boot time you may have to tell your computer it should boot from USB rather than from hard disk or CD/DVD.

Works like a charm here for years and I don't need the hassle with unflexible CD/DVDs anymore.

HTH,Perseus

Comment: I'm going to attempt that now, and hope for the best.

Comment: Tried USB, no luck, my USB stick can't boot...and I don't understand why it's not burning onto the CD...I'm at a loss. :/